# Making files in sub-folder available directly under npm import root

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am making an npm module that has this folder structure:

```
lib/
  one-icon.jsx
  another-icon.jsx
  /* about 100 more */
package.json
```

I want to be able to import them like so:

```
import OneIcon from 'icon-package/one-icon';
```

I don't want to move the files from `/lib/*` to `/*`, because that will mess up my repo, and it will make the entire project a maintenance nightmare.

Is there any way I can tell npm that `icon-package/some-icon` refers to `icon-package/lib/some-icon`?

I tried setting the `files` field in `package.json`, but that only made sure the `lib/` folder was included in the node_modules package.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can import like this?

```
import {OneIcon} from 'icon-package';
```

And having `index.js` in the package like this :-

```
export OneIcon from ‘./lib/OneIcon.jsx’
```

Comment: That would be a possibility, but each of these icon imports are a few kbs, and many of our consumers don't have the most up to date build systems that deal with dead code elimination the correct way.

In other words - `import SomeIcon from 'icon-package/some-icon` would be a few KB, while `import { SomeIcon } from 'icon-package'` would be several 100s of KBs (for those consumers).

Comment: Also, this would break our existing API, which would be a ton of work to update.